# Существует ли какой-то готовый способ для отображения таблиц из Access в Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, access

Моя программа должна отображать по выбору одну из таблиц из БД с возможностью редактирования содержимого.

Конечно, можно прочитать данные из БД, написать методы для отображения таблицы и редактирования... Но нет ли готового решения для C#?

Нашел (насколько понимаю), как вывести таблицу:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms171884(v=vs.110).aspx

Но как реализовать редактирование через таблицу, отображенную в моей программе?
Т.е., меняю значения или добавляю элементы таблицы (столбцы можно не трогать) и они сразу изменяются в БД (или в хранящейся в памяти копии для последующего сохранения).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю вам подойдет [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx) - это стандартный компонент.

В этой [статье](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial) можно посмотреть пример работы с *DataGridView*.

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже, то, что надо.